# Filter and Pagination in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, filter, pagination, asp.net-mvc-4

Its been a long day for me trying to figure this out and I believe there is always an answer on **stackoverflow**. I have searched for posts that are similar but I guess none has what am desperately looking for. Here's the deal, I have got this **MVC 4** project am working on but I ran into some issues which triggered me to throw it open. Using **IPageList** for pagination on my MVC is quite cool but how can I keep paging the result filtered using the same **ActionResult** container for the index. Here is some code to dine with.

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page, int category = 0)
     {
         int pageSize = 10;
         int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
         if (category != 0)
         {
             var products = (from p in db.Products where p.ProductID == category select p).OrderBy(x => x.ProductName).ToList();
             return View(products.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
         }
         else
         {
             var products = (from p in db.Products select p).OrderBy(x => x.ProductName).ToList();
             return View(products.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
         }
     }
```

Basically the **int category** is the value gotten from the dropdownlist. It filters perfectly but the issue is when I filter and the results is greater than 10 and I try to go to the next page, it returns to the index initial result. Debugging it, I realized once the next is clicked, the value of **int category** is cleared and it steps into the else block. Here is the paging control maybe there is something that needs to be adjusted...

```
<div>Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber)
of @Model.PageCount

@if (Model.HasPreviousPage)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("<<", "Index", new { page = 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter  })
    @Html.Raw(" ");
    @Html.ActionLink("< Prev", "Index", new { page = Model.PageNumber - 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter  })
}
else
{
    @:<<
    @Html.Raw(" ");
    @:< Prev
}

@if (Model.HasNextPage)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Next >", "Index", new { page = Model.PageNumber + 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter  })
    @Html.Raw(" ");
    @Html.ActionLink(">>", "Index", new { page = Model.PageCount, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter  })
}
else
{
    @:Next >
    @Html.Raw(" ")
    @:>>
}
```

What I need is for the filtered results returned on the page to respond to paging. I will await answers. Thanks!

Comment: try [MVC 4 Paging this MVC 4](http://nuget.org/packages/MVC4.Paging/)  Paging with bootstrap or without bootstrap design also has different options like ItemTexts, TooltipTitles, Size, Alignment, IsShowControls, ItemIcon, metro css, areas supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your action container set `ViewBag.CurrentFilter = category;` assuming CurrentFilter is category

Comment: not working... the category lost value when paging and zero is passed back to the CurrentFilter

Answer (score 4):

With the help of the previous answer and comment given by **Suhas** I was able to come out with a clearer and better solution. Here is the final solution:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page, int category = 0)
 {
     int pageSize = 10;
     int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
     if (category != 0)
     {
         ViewBag.CurrentFilter = category;
         var products = (from p in db.Products where p.ProductID == category select p).OrderBy(x => x.ProductName).ToList();
         return View(products.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
     }
     else
     {
         var products = (from p in db.Products select p).OrderBy(x => x.ProductName).ToList();
         return View(products.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
     }
 }
```

I hope it helps others out there. **Suhas** deserves the mark. Cheers!

NB: **Suhas's** comment under this solution matters alot.

Comment: I still feel this is unnecessary. If `category` and `CategoryFilter` hold the same value and are assigned from each other, then you do not need to maintain the two variables. Just setting `ViewBag.CurrentFilter = category` and changing the query string parameter in the anchor tag to `category` from `currentFilter` should do it.

Comment: Just saw your comment... If it works, I will edit my code and mark yours as the answer... Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
public PartialViewResult AllProducts(int? page, int? currentFilter, int cid = 0)
{
    ViewBag.cid = cid;
    int pageSize = 4;
    int pageIndex = 1;
    pageIndex = page.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(page) : 1;
    if (currentFilter != 0 && cid == 0)
    {
        cid = Convert.ToInt32(currentFilter);
    }
    if (cid != 0)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = cid;
        ViewBag.AllProducts = _unitOfWork.GetRepositoryInstance<tbl_Products>().GetAllRecordsIQueryable().Where(i => i.IsDelete == false && i.CategoryId == cid).ToList().ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
        return PartialView("AllProducts", ViewBag.AllProducts);
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.AllProducts = _unitOfWork.GetRepositoryInstance<tbl_Products>().GetAllRecordsIQueryable().Where(i => i.IsDelete == false).ToList().ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
        return PartialView("AllProducts", ViewBag.AllProducts);
    }
}
```

Here is the perfect code for this problem.

Comment: Can you explain *how* this helps solve the problem? A plain code block alone isn't all that informative