# MVC4 Pagination (Continued)

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

My question is a continuation of this question:

[Filter and Pagination in MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298605/filter-and-pagination-in-mvc-4/13407785)

In the code block that starts:

```
<div>Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber)
of @Model.PageCount
```

I've implemented this in my project and it works great for creating the pages and appropriate navigation links. But it doesn't pull in my actual list from the database; just page links.

Here's what I had in my Index.cshtml file before:

```
@model IEnumerable<PtoTracker.Employee>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Employees";
}

<h2>Employees</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Add New Employee", "Create")
</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.EmployeeID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.EmployeeID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.EmployeeID })
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

The above code worked great, but it was just one long list of employees. How do I merge the above code with the pagination section shown here:

```
<div>Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber)
of @Model.PageCount

@if (Model.HasPreviousPage)
{
@Html.ActionLink("<<", "Index", new { page = 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort });
@Html.Raw(" ");
@Html.ActionLink("< Prev", "Index", new { page = Model.PageNumber - 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort });
}
else
{
@:<<
@Html.Raw(" ");
@:< Prev
}

@if (Model.HasNextPage)
{
@Html.ActionLink("Next >", "Index", new { page = Model.PageNumber + 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort });
@Html.Raw(" ");
@Html.ActionLink(">>", "Index", new { page = Model.PageCount, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort });
}        
else
{
@:Next >
@Html.Raw(" ");
@:>>
}
</div>
```

Comment: If you don't want to write the paging yourself, you could use [PagedList](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList).

Comment: @jrummell I am using PagedList.

Comment: You aren't using the Html helper ... it would be one line of code for paging: `@Html.PagedListPager( (IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I just had to change the first line from `@model IEnumerable...` to `@model PageList.IPagedList...` and then slap the two chunks together.

Here's my working code:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<PtoTracker.Employee>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Employees";
}

<h2>Employees</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Add New Employee", "Create")
</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.EmployeeID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.EmployeeID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.EmployeeID })
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>

<div>
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber)
of @Model.PageCount

@if (Model.HasPreviousPage)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("<<", "Index", new { page = 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort });
    @Html.Raw(" ");
    @Html.ActionLink("< Prev", "Index", new { page = Model.PageNumber - 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort });
}
else
{
    @:<<
    @Html.Raw(" ");
    @:< Prev
}

@if (Model.HasNextPage)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Next >", "Index", new { page = Model.PageNumber + 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort });
    @Html.Raw(" ");
    @Html.ActionLink(">>", "Index", new { page = Model.PageCount, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort });
}        
else
{
    @:Next >
    @Html.Raw(" ");
    @:>>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another great alternative for Grids and Paging: [MvcContrib Grid](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid)

Comment: That link doesn't list MVC4 as supported.